# playframework2.3 run selenium tests from browser "https://host/@tests"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, playframework-2.3

How to run the selenium tests in playframwork 2.3 by running the http:/hostname:port/@tests

The method is given in this Link https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.1/test
                                                                                                         But it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I mean i am using playframework 2.3 and this testrunner feature which is mentioned in play 1.2 is not available in 2.3
Still i thought i will try that feature, 
When i try accessing my web app console "http//:server:port/@tests" it does not show me the option to run my test cases.